# Adding one to many records in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, one-to-many, sql-server-2017

I need help from someone who knows SQL, because that is a problem beyond my SQL skills. That are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders]
(
    id              INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customerName    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    customerAddress VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    submitDate      DATE NOT NULL,
    realizationDate DATE,
    deliveryTypeId  INT NOT NULL

    FOREIGN KEY(deliveryTypeId) REFERENCES deliveryTypes(id)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderItems]
(
    id              INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    orderId         INT NOT NULL,
    productId       INT NOT NULL,
    productQuantity INT,

    FOREIGN KEY(orderId) REFERENCES Orders(id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(productId) REFERENCES Products(id)
);
```

I need to create a stored procedure that inserts to two tables in the database one to many related records (in fact that's really part of many-to-many bindings, but I need to add only to these two tables). In my application (.NET) I need to pass one record "Orders" and one or more records "OrderItems".

My problems are:

- If I insert "Order" I will not know what value to set in `OrderItems -> orderId`. I found the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function, but I do not really know how to use it in my case.
- How do I insert `OrderItems` records in the table if I do not know how many of them will be? I only know that there can be one or more of them.
- I do not know how to call the procedure receiving many `OrderItems` from the application level and what arguments should I declare in the stored procedure

I really appreciate all the help, because I face a few hours with this problem and I really do not know how to do it.

EDIT : This is the code that I've come up with so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddOrder
    (@customerName    VARCHAR(30),
     @customerAddress VARCHAR(30),
     @submitDate      DATE,
     @deliveryTypeId  INT
    -- I don't know how to pass many OrderItems rows as argument
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Orders(customerName, customerAddress, submitDate, deliveryTypeId)
    VALUES (@customerName, @customerAddress, @submitDate, @deliveryTypeId)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS orderId

    -- I don't know how to do it for unknown number of rows
    INSERT INTO OrderItems(orderId, productId, productQuantity)
    VALUES (@orderId, @productId, @productQuantity)
END;
GO
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to ask in https://dba.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: @BarrJ Thanks for the suggestion, I will do it

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Comment: @mjwills I have just edit my question, thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 5):

While this question might be considered as too broad and therefor off topic, it is well written and describe a problem a lot of inexperienced developers are facing - so I think it deserves an answer.
So let's break it down to its ingredients:

1. **Q:** How to get the value of the `identity` column back after an insert?
   **A:** SQL Server provides several ways to do that, the simplest would probably be [`scope_identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but the best would be using the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.
2. **Q:** How to send multiple rows to a stored procedure?
   **A:** Use a [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

Now let's see how exactly are we going to do this.

The first thing we need to do is create a user defined table type to be used for the table valued parameter - so:

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Udt_OrderItems] AS TABLE
(
    productId       int NOT NULL,
    productQuantity int,
);
GO
```

Then, we can create a stored procedure using this type as a table valued parameter.
We will also send the order details as scalar parameters to the stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_InsertOrderWithItems
(
    @customerName    varchar(30),
    @customerAddress varchar(30),
    @submitDate      date,
    @realizationDate date,
    @deliveryTypeId  int,
    @orderItems dbo.Udt_OrderItems readonly -- Table valued parameters must be readonly
)
AS

    DECLARE @Ids AS TABLE (orderId int NOT NULL) -- for the output clause

    INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (customerName, customerAddress, submitDate, realizationDate, deliveryTypeId)
    OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @Ids
    VALUES(@customerName, @customerAddress, @submitDate, @realizationDate, @deliveryTypeId)

    INSERT INTO dbo.OrderItems (orderId, productId, productQuantity)
    SELECT orderId, productId, productQuantity
    FROM @orderItems
    CROSS JOIN @Ids -- We only have one value in @Ids so cross join is safe
GO
```

As for the c# part, It depends how are you connecting to the database - I'll show an example of the basic ADO.Net version:

```cs
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(con, "stp_InsertOrderWithItems"))
    {
        var dt = new DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("productId", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("productQuantity", typeof(int));

        // populate data table here

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = customerName;
        // all the other scalar parameters here...
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@orderItems, SqlDbType.Structured).Value = dt;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great and helpfull explanation, but could you tell me what the purpose of  orderIdint is? (stored procedure, 12 line)

Comment: It's a typo - should be `orderId int` (that's a non-nullable int column on the `@Ids` table. Answer fixed.